# Does Agora support screen share on Safari?

Tags: agora.io

i dont have a straight answer whether Agora supports screen sharing on SAFARI. This 4x api  page does not seem to list Safari at all, and there is some chatter on Stack overflow to that effect (at least for 3.x api) https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/screensharing_web_ng?platform=Web

This is a show stopper for me, so appreciate a straight answer YES or NO whether Agora supports screen sharing on safari

When i tried it, I got a getDisplayMedia error:

"getDisplayMedia must be called from a user gesture handler" on Safari 13+. I do indeed create the new client, join and publish the local video upon an actual user click on a button, so not sure why we get this error. Only happens with screen share, camera/mic work

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you answered your own question on the Agora RTE Dev Slack, I'll relay it here for anyone looking for a solution.

How Sri did it was essentially:

```
AgoraRTC.createScreenVideoTrack(..).then(() => client.join( ..)
```